# setTimeout(function() in tpl file

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I use a popup window in a tpl file. It works when entering the site. And there is close button on it. But I want to hide it automatically in five seconds too. setTimeout(function() works in a html page but I can't make it work in a tpl file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#myModal").modal('show');
});
setTimeout(function() {$('#myModal').modal('hide');}, 5000);
```

Comment: If you use `Smarty` you can remove `{literal}` `<script>` tag are sufficient @Osman

Comment: When I remove {literal} I get error message: .Fatal error: Smarty error: [in header.tpl line 154]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: jQuery("#myModal")...

Comment: Have you include `JQuery` in your script with `<script src="">` ?

Comment: I only have difficulty in the last line setTimeout(function() {$('#myModal').modal('hide');}, 5000);  Popup window works. I don't know how to use setTimeout part.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this, it should work if jQuery works:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#myModal").modal('show').delay(5000).modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: When I use your code, popup window doesn't pop. Nothing happens.